# Android: How to deserialize SoapObject to Complex Object - KSOAP2

Tags: android, soap, deserialization, ksoap2

I'm trying to deserializate a SoapRequest to Complex Object. Here's the XML response:

```
<ArrayOfECar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://testing.com/">
    <eCar>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Description>Fiat</Description>
        <Drivers>
            <eDriver>
                <Id>1</Id>
                <Description>Lucas</Description>
            </eDriver>
            <eDriver>
                <Id>2</Id>
                <Description>John</Description>
            </eDriver>
        </Drivers>
    </eCar>
    <eCar>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Description>Ford</Description>
        <Drivers>
            <eDriver>
                <Id>1</Id>
                <Description>Charly</Description>
            </eDriver>
            <eDriver>
                <Id>2</Id>
                <Description>Harry</Description>
            </eDriver>
        </Drivers>
    </eCar>
</ArrayOfECar>
```

Now, in my Android Project, I create the Object Classes implements KvmSerializable, like this:

Car Class:

```
public class Car implements KvmSerializable {
    private int id;
    private String description;
    private ArrayDriver drivers;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public ArrayDriver getDrivers() {
        return drivers;
    }
    public void setDrivers(ArrayDriver drivers) {
        this.drivers = drivers;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(int index) {
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                return getId();
            case 1:
                return getDescription();
            case 2:
                return getDrivers();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPropertyCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                setId(Integer.parseInt(value.toString()));
                break;
            case 1:
                setDescription(value.toString());
                break;
            case 2:
                setDrivers((ArrayDriver)value);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable properties, PropertyInfo info) {
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                info.name = "Id";
                info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
                break;
            case 1:
                info.name = "Description";
                info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                break;
            case 2:
                info.name = "Drivers";
                info.type = ArrayDriver.class;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Driver Class:

```
public class Driver implements KvmSerializable {
    private int id;
    private String description;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(int index) {
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                return getId();
            case 1:
                return getDescription();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPropertyCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                setId(Integer.parseInt(value.toString()));
                break;
            case 1:
                setDescription(value.toString());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable properties, PropertyInfo info) {
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                info.name = "Id";
                info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
                break;
            case 1:
                info.name = "Description";
                info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And arrays like this:

ArrayCar Class:

```
public class ArrayCar extends Vector<Car> implements KvmSerializable {

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(int index) {
        return this.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getPropertyCount() {
        return this.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
        this.add((Car)value);
    }

    @Override
    public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable properties, PropertyInfo info) {
        info.name = "eCar";
        info.type = Car.class;
    }
}
```

ArrayDriver Class:

```
public class ArrayDriver extends Vector<Driver> implements KvmSerializable {

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(int index) {
        return this.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getPropertyCount() {
        return this.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
        this.add((Driver)value);
    }

    @Override
    public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable properties, PropertyInfo info) {
        info.name = "eDriver";
        info.type = Driver.class;
    }
}
```

And now here's the AsyncTask that I'm using to deserialize XML to ArrayCar:

```
String SOAP_ACTION = "http://testing.com/getCars";
String METHOD_NAME = "getCars";

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "eCar", Car.class);
envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "eDriver", Driver.class);

HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
transport.debug = true;
try {
    transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    return (ArrayCar) envelope.getResponse();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("TEST", "KSOAP2", e);
}
return null;
```

But it's not working, throw this Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject cannot be cast to com.oseas.wsconsumer.entities.ArrayCar
```

I know that I can deserialize it manually, looping by each property in SoapObject, etc. But I want to know if there is one way to make it more easy and automatic.

Sorry for bad english, I hope you understand.